# GCP won't provision SSL certs for Load Balancer w/ HTTPS redirect

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform, load-balancer

If I have 2 ip addresses in the A record to enable the http->https redirect, the cert provisioner can't seem to see find it. Checking the DNS propagation seems okay.

What would be happening here?

#### SSL

---

[image]

### Load Balancers

---

[image]

### DNS

---

[image]

Comment: You must use the same IP address for the load balancer frontends for ports 80 and 443.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to set a global external IP and assign that to the load balancer and the A record.